# Javascript not passing through on local webview page

Tags: javascript, java, android, canvas, webview

Hi I am trying to make an android application that you can draw on a canvas and I found html was the easiest to do this. I grabbed a couple of code samples and created a project, I am only 1/2 way done and I am stuck on this little frustrating part. When I click on a button in the menu to clear the canvas, the javascript doesn't pass through and clear the canvas on the html page. Here is my code...
MainActivity.java

```
package tk.leoforney.ftcscorer;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WebView htmlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.fieldPad);
        WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        htmlWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearCanvas);
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                            htmlWebView.evaluateJavascript("newCanvas()", null);
                        } else {
                            htmlWebView.loadUrl("javascript:newCanvas()");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        htmlWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

        String htmlFilename = "index.html";
        AssetManager mgr = getBaseContext().getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream in = mgr.open(htmlFilename, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);
            String htmlContentInStringFormat = StreamToString(in);
            in.close();
            htmlWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlContentInStringFormat, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static String StreamToString(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        if(in == null) {
            return "";
        }
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
        }
        return writer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coaches playbook</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx, color = "#000";

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // setup a new canvas for drawing wait for device init
        setTimeout(function(){
           newCanvas();
        }, 1000);

        // reset palette selection (css) and select the clicked color for canvas strokeStyle
        $(".palette").click(function(){
            $(".palette").css("border-color", "#777");
            $(".palette").css("border-style", "solid");
            $(this).css("border-color", "#fff");
            $(this).css("border-style", "dashed");
            color = $(this).css("background-color");
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        });

        // link the new button with newCanvas() function
        $("#new").click(function() {
            newCanvas();
        });
    });

    // function to setup a new canvas for drawing
    function newCanvas(){
        //define and resize canvas
        $("#content").height($(window).height());
        var canvas = '<canvas id="canvas" width="'+$(window).width()+'" height="'+$(window).height()+'"></canvas>';
        $("#content").html(canvas);

        // setup canvas
        ctx=document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;


        // setup to trigger drawing on mouse or touch
        $("#canvas").drawTouch();
        $("#canvas").drawPointer();
        $("#canvas").drawMouse();
        var canvasHeight
    }

    // prototype to start drawing on touch using canvas moveTo and lineTo
    $.fn.drawTouch = function() {
        var start = function(e) {
            e = e.originalEvent;
            ctx.beginPath();
            x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
            y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
            ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        };
        var move = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e = e.originalEvent;
            x = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
            y = e.changedTouches[0].pageY;
            ctx.lineTo(x,y);
            ctx.stroke();
        };
        $(this).on("touchstart", start);
        $(this).on("touchmove", move);
    };

    // prototype to start drawing on pointer(microsoft ie) using canvas moveTo and lineTo
    $.fn.drawPointer = function() {
        var start = function(e) {
            e = e.originalEvent;
            ctx.beginPath();
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
            ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        };
        var move = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e = e.originalEvent;
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
            ctx.lineTo(x,y);
            ctx.stroke();
        };
        $(this).on("MSPointerDown", start);
        $(this).on("MSPointerMove", move);
    };

    // prototype to start drawing on mouse using canvas moveTo and lineTo
    $.fn.drawMouse = function() {
        var clicked = 0;
        var start = function(e) {
            clicked = 1;
            ctx.beginPath();
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
            ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        };
        var move = function(e) {
            if(clicked){
                x = e.pageX;
                y = e.pageY;
                ctx.lineTo(x,y);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        };
        var stop = function(e) {
            clicked = 0;
        };
        $(this).on("mousedown", start);
        $(this).on("mousemove", move);
        $(window).on("mouseup", stop);

        $(document).ready(function () {
            if(window.location.indexOf("newCanvas") >= 0)
            {
                 newCanvas();
            }
        });
    };
</script>
    <style>
        body {
        margin:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        font-family:Arial;
        /* prevent text selection on ui */
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        /* prevent scrolling in windows phone */
        -ms-touch-action: none;
        /* prevent selection highlight */
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        }

        #content{
        position: absolute;
        top:0px;
        bottom: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-color:#fff;
        }
        #canvas {
        cursor: crosshair;
        background: url('field.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-position: center top;
        top:0px;
        bottom: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div id="content"><p style="text-align:center">Loading Canvas...</p></div>
    <!--    <div class="footer">
            <div class="palette-case">
                <div id="new" class="action-button">Clear</div>
                <div class="palette-box">
                    <div class="palette red"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="palette-box">
                    <div class="palette blue"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div></div> -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context="tk.leoforney.ftcscorer"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fieldPad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="365dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!--
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
     -->
    <item android:id="@+id/clearCanvas" android:title="@string/action_clear" android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

If anybody can figure this out that would be awesome! thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I just had to move the button click event down to the oncreateoptionsmenu function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load script in local Web-view so you can use `loadDataWithBaseURL` method.

First of all Put all your javascript under an **assets** folder  (as you want local so otherwise give URL of javascript file) and give JS file path relative to the assets folder in your script tag (in the html). Don't put a slash in the beginning of src.

Read the `HTML` into a string (htmlString) and then load it in the webview as following below.

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

It's for fine in my project.

Comment: It doesn't work, it only shows a textbox that says "index.html" My code is here http://pastebin.com/q1Mq0SR4